# Symfony3 Doctrine Single Table Inhertiance SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I am new to Symfony and I am trying to do a simple Blog. I have users in my database as authors of Comments and 2 types of comments - PostComment and ReplyComment which both extend abstract class Comments. I am trying to save comment to the DB, but I am stuck with this error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO comment (text,
>   author_id, post_id, comment_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params
>   ["Lorem ipsum", 1, 1, "post_comment"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`blog_symfony`.`comment`, CONSTRAINT `FK_9474526CDB1174D2` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`post_comment_id`) REFERENCES `comment` (`id`))

This is abstract Comment Class :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="comment_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"post_comment" = "PostComment", "reply_comment" = "ReplyComment"})
 */
abstract class Comment
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userComments")
     */
    protected $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $text;

    /**
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string $author
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $author
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;
    }

    /**
     * @return string $text
     */
    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $text
     */
    public function setText($text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }
}
```

This is a post comment class

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostCommentRepository")
 */
class PostComment extends Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Post", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ReplyComment", mappedBy="postComment", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"id"="DESC"})
     */

    private $replyComments;

    /**
     * @return replyComment[] reply comments
     */
    public function getReplyComments()
    {
        return $this->replyComments;
    }

    /**
     * @param replyComment[] reply comments
     */
    public function setReplyComments($replyComments)
    {
        $this->replyComments = $replyComments;
    }

    /**
     * @return Post post
     */
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    /**
     * @param Post post
     */
    public function setPost($post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
    }
}
```

And finally this is the code in controller runnig logic

```
if ($postCommentForm->isSubmitted() && $postCommentForm->isValid())
        {
            /** @var PostComment $comment */
            $comment = $postCommentForm->getData();
            $comment->setPost($post);

            $author = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy([
                'email' => $comment->getAuthor()
            ]);

            $comment->setAuthor($author);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($comment);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute("single_post", [
                'id' => $post->getId()
            ]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

At first your base class don't need to be abstract. Instead you have to insert this annotation above the class, so doctrine will get it:

```
@MappedSuperclass()
```

remove all other doctrine annotations from base entity, all of them belongs to the entity class.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *@MappedSuperclass()
 */
class Comment
{
```

and entity have all other annotations:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostCommentRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment")
 */
class PostComment extends Comment
{
```

this should help

Comment: then you can check the answer